# two input into an arraylist list

Tags: java, arraylist

Super newb here. My assigmentment requires me to take 2 input (instrument name and cost) from another class, use an arraylist and printout. I created class object into an array, but for some reason, compiler can't find methods. Here's the intruction I need to follow:

Implement `addToPurchaseCart(MusicalInstrument instrument, int quantity)`, which will first check to see that the number of Instruments purchased does not exceed the number currently in stock. If the number being purchased is OK, then add that number of `Instruments` to the purchased `ArrayList`. Also, don’t forget to delete the same number of `Instruments` from the inventory.

Here's what I got:

```
public class ShoppingCart

private ArrayList<MusicalInstrument> shopInstrument;

public ShoppingCart();
this.shopInstrument     = new ArrayList<MusicalInstrument>();

public void addToPurchaseCart(MusicalInstrument instrument, int quantity){
        shopInstrument     = new ArrayList<MusicalInstrument>();
        shopInstrument.getDescription(instrument);
        shopInstrument.getQuantitySold(quantity);
        }
```

Compiler can't find: `shopInstrument.getDescription` and `shopInstrument.getQuantitySold`
Also, what do I use to delete from the list?

---

> Update

---

I got compiler to find `shopInstrument.getDescription` and `shopInstrument.getQuantitySold.

My next question is how do I put this in a table like format? The instruction said to use arraylist, so I created an array list for each method...I still need to figure out why im getting error. But once I get through error, how do I create two arraylist into a table.

It needs to arrange like this:

```
kazzoo      $2.00
kazzoo      $2.00
kazzoo      $2.00
tambourine  $2.00
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the code of MusicalInstrument?

Comment: shopInstrument is a ArrayList, you can't call the method on the ArrayList. maybe you should call the method on the inventory object.

Comment: MusicalInstrument is a class to add instruments, prices and stock.

Comment: Call method on inventory object, then convert to ArrayList? I'll try that out. Thanks

Comment: The shopInstrument property should be: List<MusicalInstrument>. Use the interface, not the specific collection type.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it wasn't right and the question has now changed.
@roach, dude you really need to paste the code for the target class of your question, so we can understand what you have and what is going on. Also, please correct the code where you call the `getDescription` and `getQuantitySold` from the ArrayList.

Comment: I'll do that next time Ric...thanks